# IE7 trouble with jquery mobile application

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm making one `webapplication` with `JQuery Mobile`.
In actual browser, all is ok, but not in `IE7`. I know, it's a `mobile application` but someone want to use with a regular  computer, and I will not change the whole `layout`.

Anyways, I have one `header`, and this header is centred between two spaces. We cannot see those spaces in actual "great" browsers, but in IE7, he doesn't :-/ **I want no space!**

I saw that the "space" is bigger with a higher height of the window :

[image: Error when fullscreen]

[image: Error when fullscreen height * 2]

This is the `HTML` generated by `IE7` :

```
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c" class="applicationheader">
                                <img src="http://application.local/applicationlogo.png" alt="application" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" />
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

**EDIT:**

When I do a "background color: red", the zone to hide is red, but when I make a "max height:1px", nothing move!

Comment: why is anyone still using IE7? What is stopping him from at least updating to IE8?

Comment: @Spudley : application have to run on one machine with custom enterprise OS (windows XP edited with applications and so on) and the don't have the right to install new one :'(

Comment: oh well, fair enough. I would suggest adding an extra charge to your invoice for having to support such an old browser though.

Comment: @Spudley : HAHA thanks for the advice :-) super-fat-extra-charge :D

Answer (score 1):

Good luck with that. *jQuery Mobile* is not intended to work in IE7 at all. Actually, even new *jQuery* branch 2.x dropped support of this browser.

You can try to find a CSS rule which causes this misbehavior in IE7 and override it with `*` CSS hack targeted at IE7. More info here: http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/

Comment: okay thanks. Humm I can make the "wrong" zone black thanks to "background-color: black", but I can't fox the height of this background... argh